# pairwise t test on two samples with different size

Tags: t-test, multiple-comparisons

I saw some questions here but none had helped to answer. I have a two different groups orthodox and southpaw. I am trying to calculate if orthodox have a higher win percentage than a southpaw or vise Versa. However, my sample size for orthodox is 391 and for southpaw 89. Can someone advise if that's ok or not? What would be the alternative if it is not.

Comment: I don't think you have a basis for pairing. So if a t test is appropriate it should be unpaired.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I think you might be right and I should use unpaired. However, how about the sample sizes? @MichaelR.Chernick

Comment: Use Welch's t-test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test It accounts for unequal variance and/or unequal sample sizes.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan I will do that